# nginx reverse proxy gives 400 when defining location

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to create a reverse proxy to access my ip camera (10.10.10.31). But for some reason when I try to change my location from `"/"` to `"/cam1"` I get a `400 bad request`. I can see it is trying to acces `10.10.10.31/cam1` but that does not exist.

How can I make it possible to go to someWebsite/cam1 and then get redirected to 10.10.10.31/

This works:

```
server {
    listen 50000;
    server_name someWebsite;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.31/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;
}
```

This does not work:

```
server {
    listen 50000;
    server_name someWebsite;

    location /cam1 {
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.31/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem and solve it by comment out the

```
# proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

and the problem solved. Still don't know why

Comment: I completly forgot i asked this question. the way i solved it at the time was by changing each cam to be a seperate server and also added the proxypass line. so it looked like this
`
server {
     listen 500000;
     server_name  cam1.*;

     #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

     location / {
         proxy_pass http://camIP/;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     }
}
`

Comment: @somedude you should and still can add it as an answer to your own question and should mark it as accepted answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).